# Como carregar propriedade do tipo Enum numa Lambda

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma propriedade desse tipo

```
public CustomerTypeRequest Type { get; set; }
```

Esse tipo(`CustomerTypeRequest`) é um enum, conforme abaixo

```
public enum CustomerTypeRequest
    {
        Guest = 0, //Visitante anônimo
        Customer = 1, //Cliente final
        Reseller = 2, //Vendedor de uma revenda
    }
```

Preciso agora numa Lambda trazer todos os que são 1 ou Customer, tipo assim

```
var qry = customer.Where(x => x.Type == 1);
```

O que passa é que assim dá erro e já tentei com equals também, não dá erro, mas não gera dados. O erro é esse:

> O operador '==' não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos
>   "CustomerTypeRequest" e "int"

Como filtro minha lista por esse campo do tipo Enum?

Comment: Dessa forma: `var qry = customer.Where(x => x.Type == CustomerTypeRequest.Customer);`

Comment: Responde que eu marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira é comparar com o `Enum` `CustomerTypeRequest` que é o tipo que está configurado no seu Modelo:

```
var qry = customer.Where(x => x.Type == CustomerTypeRequest.Customer);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var qry = customer.Where(x => x.Type == CustomerTypeRequest.Customer);
```

ou

```
var qry = customer.Where(x => (int)x.Type == 1);
```